# Trying to draw Kenyan flag colours in python, encountered name error?

Tags: python, variables, syntax

I thought trying to draw this thing in kenyan colours. Thought it would be simple and quick but ran into errors on the second line.

import turtle
pen=turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed('fastest')

When I take out the second line the error appears on the third line.

What am I doing wrong?

```
turtle.bgcolor('black')
col=('black','white','red','white','green')
```

That's what I'm trying to get to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used turtle myself, but after looking online I found this section of code which compiles:

```
from turtle import *

color('red', 'yellow')
begin_fill()
while True:
    forward(200)
    left(170)
    if abs(pos()) < 1:
        break
end_fill()
done()
```

From that I think your issue is how you are importing. Try importing turtle the same way as above, and then do:

```
color('black','white','red','white','green')
```

instead of

```
col=('black','white','red','white','green')
```

---Update-to-address-comments---

Looking at your code, let me know if I misinterpreted where white space should be.

```
from turtle import * 
pen=turtle.Turtle() 
pen.speed('fastest') 
turtle.bgcolor('black') 
color=('black','white','red','white','green')  
for i in range(1,200,2):   
    t.pencolor(col[i%4])   
    for x in range(0,10):     
        t.circle(i)     
        t.rt(50)      
turtle.done()
```

Your issue isn't the import it's the use of t. instead of pen. New code should look like this:

```
import turtle 
pen=turtle.Turtle() 
pen.speed('fastest') 
turtle.bgcolor('black') 
color=('black','white','red','white','green')  
for i in range(1,200,1):   
    pen.pencolor(color[i%4])   
    for x in range(0,10):     
        pen.circle(i)     
        pen.rt(50)      
turtle.done()
```

<strike>The colors don't seem to work though. I'll look into it a bit more in a few minutes.</strike>

note the for loop should iterate by 1 not 2 for the colors to switch properly.

Comment: I'm grateful for the quick response.

Comment: Tried both solutions as described but the error remains. Error code as follows:

Comment: Sorry about the lack of white space. I'll try again.

Comment: '''TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-7c384b70a73e> in <module>()
      1 from turtle import *
----> 2 pen=turtle.Turtle()'''

Comment: `from turtle import *
pen=turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed('fastest')

turtle.bgcolor('black')
color=('black','white','red','white','green')

for i in range(1,200,2):
  t.pencolor(col[i%4])
  for x in range(0,10):
    t.circle(i)
    t.rt(50)

    turtle.done()`

Comment: I'm looking at turtle.py to see if there are any clues there.

Comment: I made some edits with the new info